# Google Webmaster Tools shows "No Structured Data"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, structured-data

I don't know why but for some reason Google Webmaster Tools says that the website has no structured data and I don't understand why.

The website does have a structure and I made sure that It was well structured. The [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) doesn't give me errors. Can the reason be that the website redirects to its language specific page on load? For example, `https://www.example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com/en` or `https://www.example.com/az` based on region.

What do I need to do for this to work out?

Comment: The website is https://www.noc-aze.org/. I put this here as I edit the question to prevent it from being closed for being about one particular site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structured data refers to data markup. It's not about the general structure of the site.
More info here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/

Comment: This makes sense now. I already have all the schema.org tags but I guess I have missed some